# How ot float menu left in overflow-x using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, overflow

How can I get third level menu to float left Incase overflow-x 
here is my current CSS [image: I want the submenu to float left instead of scrolling the whole page horizontally]

```
&:hover {
    ul {
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        overflow-x: auto;
        left:100%;
        //top: 1%;
        margin-top: -22px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    li {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish from this single line of text and code block.  Could you show a screen shot of what you're trying to do, and maybe spend a little bit of time explaining?

Comment: I want the submenu to float left instead of scrolling the whole page horizontally

Comment: This is going to be a little bit more complex than simple CSS, I think.  It looks like you're going to have to use JavaScript to detect if it runs off the edge of the page.

Comment: Indeed, CSS cannot detect overflow. Javascript is required.

Answer (score -1):

```
&:hover {
    ul {
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        overflow-x: auto;
        left:0; 
        //top: 1%;
        margin-top: -22px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    li {
        float:right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give an explanation of your answer.  Just including css is not as helpful as explaining why this works.